# How can I find and replace different values in a large dataset in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Say I'm having a large dataset with column 'A' with different codes, like 00HY789, 0HYJM45, but also 7890, 5678 and I want to transform all the string values into numerical codes:

I have a list (column 'B') where every string has a cooresponding numerical code (column 'C') and this list has 97000 entries. So basically, I want to know if I can replace all string codes from column 'A' with their corresponding codes from column 'C'.

Is there a way that excel can look into the 'B' column, for all the 'A' column variables and find the corresponding code within the 'C' column and replace the initial 'A' column variable with the 'C' column code?

Thank you

Comment: There is a way - it is called VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this formula in cell D1:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,0),A1)
```

It will assign value if found and if not found it will assign A1 value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I place the formula, it seems that excel doesn't know what to do. An error message pops up, quoting there is an error with this formula. It points out this part of the formula "(A1,B: " . What do you think I m doing wrong? I m so sorry, I'm new using excel. Thank you.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;B:C;2;0);A1)

Comment: Try above (different separator)

Comment: Thank you. It's still not working. When I copy and paste it, this is what appears as result: #Name?. I tried with different rows, still the same result.

Comment: Show a screen shot.

Comment: Sorry I m trying to upload a foto. This is a copy paste of the rows. #¿NOMBRE?
#¿NOMBRE?
#¿NOMBRE?
#¿NOMBRE?
#¿NOMBRE?
#¿NOMBRE?

Comment: Ok, might be better for you if you read this article and actually understand how vlookup works instead of copying a ready solution: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

Comment: Also it seems that you are using a non-english version of excel - which is why it cannot find vlookup. It is probably named differently. http://www.excelfunctions.eu/VLOOKUP/English-Spanish

Comment: Ok. thank you very much. I 'll let you know afterwards. So sorry.

Comment: It worked, the 2nd formula. I translated it to my office language. Thank you very much and I m so sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :) I'm glad I could help.